# Cant render EJS file as a Response to POST request

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I've just started learning Express and Servers.

**Problem**

Just wanted to load another EJS page onto my localhost:4000/ path as a response after a POST request has been made for a form.

However, although I do get the response of the EJS page with the data from the req.body in the form from the client-side. I can't seem to get the page to load on the browser.

Any ideas? pls help

[image: Picture of my problem here]

```
Express.js Server

let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let path = require('path');
let fs = require('fs');

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true});


app.use(express.json());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/views/partial'));

//Handling the GET request with the render of EJS file "index"
app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
  res.render('index');
});

//Handling the POST request from the client, and sending the EJS file "createAccount" as a response
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  res.set('cache-control', 'max-age=0; private; no-cache');
  res.render('createAccount', {data:req.body}); //
});

app.listen(4000, ()=>{
  console.log('Port 4000 has been called');
});
```

***EDIT:***
I've included the JS file which I am using to make the POST request below.

```
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', Master); 

async function Master(){
  
  console.log("Button clicked")

  const username = document.querySelector("#username").value;
  const password = document.querySelector("#password").value;

  let results = {
      "username": username, 
      "password": password
  };

  console.log(results);

    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
      body: JSON.stringify(results)
    };

    const post = await fetch('/', options);

    
};
```

Comment: Provide the index.ejs file, or the way you send the post request.

Comment: hello, i've edited my original question to include the JS file I use to make the POST request!

Comment: You use an XHR request to send a request, your browser will not update anything until you update it manually. You can submit the request as a normal HTML form, or get the response and update your UI like: `$('#body').html(await post.text());`

Comment: Sorry dude, I'm pretty new to all this so hope you dont mind me asking. Are you suggesting that I would need to include that line as part of the JS file at the very end to handle the response, and update the UI subsequently?

Comment: `const post = await fetch('/', options); $('body').html(await post.text());`

Answer (score 0):

The point of Ajax is to make an HTTP request and **process the response with JS** without rendering a whole new page.

If you want to render that response then you need to write JS to do so.

That said, you would likely be better off **not using Ajax**. Submit a regular HTML form without the interference of JS, and have your server side code use a body parser suited to URLEncoded data (since that is how forms encode data by default).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is a correct question lol but is it ok to have the same "/" in get and post request? Why not put something in it.

> app.post("/create")

then also change this

> const post = await fetch('/create', options);

Comment: “ but is it ok to have the same "/" in get and post request?” - yes. It’s absolutely  fine.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of rendering your ejs file , you better use : app.redirect("/your_path_name")

Comment: That won’t help. The Ajax API will handle the redirect and then the OP’s JS will ignore the data returned from the new URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).